# I´m working on React Native , and i don´t understand this diference to make a setState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-maps

```
export interface Location{
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}

const [routeLines, setRouteLines] = useState<Location []>([]);
```

When I use `setRouteLines( routes => [...routes, location])` works, but I try this `setRouteLines([...routeLines, location])`doesn't works.  I don´t understand the difference.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of when you tried it and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the answer might be because using the `routeLines` for the previous value is not accurate.

React might do something called [Batch](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) when states change over time.

As a result, [using the callback in `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) will [guaruntee](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#basic-hooks) you are using the most recent state to make updates.

Comment: Adding: In each one of them, the `routes` means a different thing, React-wise. You should use the callback option